# Edge Animate Start Animation From JS

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-edge

I just made my first edge animate project and made a fancy progress loader animation. Works well within animate and in a test project.

When I placed the code in the dev site the animation was loaded into every page, so I hid it with CSS. It seems to be the default that it's just loaded up.

When my animation is needed i'm making is visible however the animation has already been started in the background when its shown its no in the right place.

I'm wondering should I stop the stage autoplay in the config and then start the animation in JS? If so how can I go about starting the animation via JS.

I've been playing around with `AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback()` but again the projects already started in the background.

Answer (score 4):

OK i found the solution after posting on Adobe forums.

I was directed to [this article](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5289458#5289458#5289458).

So when the animation is loaded this callback is performed.

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function (compId) {

comps = AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId).getStage();

});
```

So in my example comps is a global variable which can be used to interact with the animation.

So in my case i needed to play the animation from the start.

```
comps.play(0);
```

Hope that helps if someone has the same issue.